# How do I get a list of strings ending in a newline or ending in the end of the string in javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm pretty frustrated with regex right now. Given:

```
var text = "This is a sentence.\nThis is another sentence\n\nThis is the last sentence!"
```

I want regex to return to me:

```
{"This is a sentence.\n", "This is another sentence\n\n", "This is the last sentence!"}
```

I think i should use

```
var matches = text.match(/.+[\n+\Z]/)
```

but \Z doesn't seem to work. Does javascript have an end of string matcher?

Comment: (.+\n*) see it here: https://regex101.com/r/wK8oX3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: `/(.+\n*)/g`

See it here: http://regex101.com/r/wK8oX3/1

Comment: what do brackets do if there's not any | characters in there?

Comment: as brackets you mean `(`

Comment: Yeah, they aren't really necessary. /.+\n*/g  works ok

Comment: The parenteshis is just to create grouping functions. You are right on your case it is not necessary. I like to use it because further on if I need to use group values on replacing it will be easy to identify the group parts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex.

```
var matches = text.match(/.+\n*/g);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/253016)

Or you could match a newline sequence "one or more" times or the end of the string.

```
var matches = text.match(/.+(?:\n+|$)/g);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Well, I've been at it for 12 hours now. What can I expect..

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted an array and didn't want to keep the `"\n"` around you could do...

```
var strings = text.split("\n");
```

which would yield

```
["This is a sentence.", "This is another sentence", "", "This is the last sentence!"]
```

if you wanted to get rid of that empty string chain a filter onto the split...

```
var strings = text.split("\n").filter(function(s){ return s !== ""; });
```

Maybe not what you want tho, also not as efficient as the regex options already proposed.

Edit: as torazaburo pointed out using `Boolean` as the filter function is cleaner than a callback.

```
var strings = text.split("\n").filter(Boolean);
```

Edit Again: I keep getting one upped, using the `/\n+/` expression is even cooler.

```
var strings = text.split(/\n+/);
```

Comment: `filter(Boolean)` is cleaner.

Comment: You could split on `\n+` instead to avoid the empty string in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of sentences:

```
var matches = text.match(/.+?(?:(?:\\n)+|$)/g);
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the double backslash before `n`?

Comment: @torazaburo if the text contains \n then you have to match the backslash with \\ and the n with n. If you want to match a linebreak directly you just have to remove one \ before the n

Comment: But the string given by the OP does not contain a literal backslash, it contains a newline, which is what `\n` means in JavaScript literal strings. Your `\\n` would match a literal backslash followed by the `n`, which would not be present in the input string unless it had been specified as `"This is a sentence.\\n..."`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

text.match(/.+/g)

Comment: This eats the newlines, but the OP wants to keep them.